# How to run NPM run script passing env variable (calling the appropriate env.{env} file)?

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables, dotenv

I'm on NodeJs app, I've create two files:

```
.env
.env.production
```

on the first I have dev settings, on the later prod settings.

Now, running on local, I'd like to do this:

```
npm run jobs_orders
```

Configured this way within package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "job_orders": "supervisor --mode production jobs/job_orders.js",
},
```

But later on app, when doing:

```
import 'dotenv/config';
...
process.env.DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING
```

it always read the `DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING` settings on .env file, not the one on env.production.

Where am I wrong? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `dotenv` will load the environment variables located in `path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env')` by default.

You can set the `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable to determine which `.env` to load for different environments.

`index.mjs`:

```js
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import path from 'path';

const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || '';

config({ path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), `.env${nodeEnv ? '.' + nodeEnv : ''}`) });

console.log('process.env.DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING: ', process.env.DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING);
```

`.env`

```
DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING=dev
```

`.env.production`

```
DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING=prd
```

Development:

```
$ node index.mjs 
process.env.DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING:  dev
```

Production:

```
$ NODE_ENV=production node index.mjs 
process.env.DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING:  prd
```

Reference:

- [react-scripts/config/env.js](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/0a827f69ab0d2ee3871ba9b71350031d8a81b7ae/packages/react-scripts/config/env.js#L26)
- [What other .env files can be used?](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used)

Node version: v14.21.3

Comment: ok with set NODE_ENV=production& supervisor jobs/job_orders.js it works. thanks!

Comment: @markzzz The solution is the same no matter you use CJS or ESM